# Disable "preview changes" button

Tags: publish, post-editor, previews

How can I hide the "preview changes" button from the admin panel?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Please replace $post_type with your post_type in question, e.g. post, page, cpt_slug,…

The function echoing the meta box with the preview button is called [`post_submit_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_submit_meta_box/#source-code). The condition to show the button is set with the function [`is_post_type_viewable`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_viewable/#source-code). Following that: If the {$post_type}s flags `publicly_queryable` or `_builtin` and `public` are set to `true` the preview button will be shown. That means all publicly queryable built-in post types will have that button anyway. For CPTs you can adapt the flags, if you don't need them publicly queryable.

### What if I want to publicly query my $post_type, but don't want a preview button?

You are out of luck for an easy solution. But there is always a workaround:

1. Hide the Button with custom CSS that you load on condition of screens `post.php`/`post-new.php` and your $post_type.
2. Hide the Button with JS on the same condition.
3. Remove the meta box and replace it with your own. Here some code to get you started.

   ```
   function add_custom_submit_box() {
       $publish_callback_args = null;
       //TODO: Add revisions support if needed, see wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php Line 219 if needed.
       remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', $post_type, 'side');
       add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'my_{$post_type}_submit_meta_box', $post_type, 'side', 'core', $publish_callback_args );
   }

   add_action('init','add_custom_submit_box');

   function my_{$post_type}_submit_meta_box( $post, $args = array() ) {
       //TODO: Copy & paste post_submit_meta_box function and adapt to your needs.
   }
   ```